# cURL - cannot send files from server 1 to server 2

Tags: php, apache, curl, ftp, file-transfer

I have 2 servers on aws. I am trying to move files from server1 to server2. This is my code on server1 -

```
function moveFileToServer2($filepath, $target_url){
        $cFile = null;
        if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
            $cFile = curl_file_create($filepath);
        } else {
            $cFile = '@' . realpath($filepath);
        }
        if($cFile != null){
            $post = array('file_contents'=> $cFile);
            try{
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                $result = curl_exec ($ch);
            }catch(Exception $e){
                 //catch exception
            }finally{
                curl_close ($ch);
            }
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

All the file paths are correct (absolute and relative everything). I have verified them.

This is my code on server2 (curl_file_receiver.php ) -

```
<?php
    //some other stuff here         
    $output_dir = "../uploads/";

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_contents"]["tmp_name"], $output_dir);
    echo json_encode(1);
    exit;
?>
```

This code is not moving the file to server 2. I tried passing other parameters with curl, and I was able to establish connection and pass string data.

Here, when my CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option is set to `true` I am receiving empty array in my curl result.

When my CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION is set to `false`, I am receiving an HTML in my result saying this -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://<server-path>/curl_file_receiver.php?<some-other-params>"here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at -server-name- Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Either ways, I am not receiving any files on server 2. This code is working fine on my local machine. (i.e, if I send file from one application to another on same XAMPP server) (Each server hosts a PHP project)
Can someone please tell me what is going wrong? Is it some curl/php setting I need to enable on my aws server? Or is it some curl option I need to set?

Also, I need to be able to send files on https on my production server, I have turned off CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER. A solutions which can send files on https would help me a lot.

Comment: That's a lot of code you want people to read. For tips about writing good questions, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry, as requested, I edited my code. Can you please point me in the right direction.